# Whats a better approach to implementing web api

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I'm just wondering what would be the better approach to calling a Web api method?  The pros and cons?

option1. 
Calling the web api from an ajax post

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'localhost/api/user/adduser',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ Id: Id }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

or option2.
An ajax post to a client controller and then use a rest client to call the web api

```
      $.ajax({
            url: 'user/adduser/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ Id: Id }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

And calling the api

```
    public ActionResult addUser(int id)
    {
        var api = new RestClient("http://localhost:60081/api/");
        var request = new RestRequest("/user/adduser", Method.POST);
        var result = new User();
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddJsonBody(id);
       var resp = api.Execute(req);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the api and you don't need to further enrich the API call, my personal preference is option 1 as it saves unnecessary code.

If it's an external api such as Instagram's API, I prefer option 2- as then I can enrich the API with additional info like AccessToken's that I want private (rather than embedded in the JS).